# Why am I getting this error?

Tags: 7

I am getting this error.

> Call to undefined function feeds_node_prepare() in dkan_datastore_node_update() (line 307 of /dkan/dkan/profiles/dkan/modules/dkan/dkan_datastore/dkan_datastore.module).

What could be causing the error? Could it be a module interfering with function?

Comment: Any feedback to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is referenced in [Dkan developpers Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dkan-dev/rZs4eQVVduc).

You probably have updated Feeds modules in Dkan profiles folder? Read the above post carefully and consider trying proposed solution :

- Keep the Dkan profile original code in place
- Download [Feeds 7.x-2.0-beta4](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/releases/7.x-2.0-beta4) to sites/all/modules/contrib
- Rebuild registry

**EDIT :** I browsed both Feeds and Dkan feeds.module history. I couldn't find any implementation of `feeds_node_prepare()` in Feeds, while Dkan contrib feeds.module does implement it.

Seems that Feeds in DKAN profile contrib modules directory is a fork, not official release.

Comment: So, I have to put the feeds module in that directory and that should do it?

Comment: Nope. 3 steps : first revert Feeds to Dkan version in Dkan profile, then put last Feeds release in contrib folder, last rebuild registry.